# How to encrypt a cookie for the token to be unreadable

Tags: c#, cookies, token

So I know you probably get this a lot but I'm just gonna ask it anyway.

I'm building an Authentication System for my MVC ASP.Net project and I want users to log in and stay logged in using an authentication token stored in a cookie on the client's pc.

My question is:

Say I create a token and store it on the client's computer.

If someone wants to use their log in account can't they just access that person's cookie, copy the token paste it on their PC and create a cookie with the same token and be logged in just like that?

I assume that there's some sort of method where the server encrypts the cookie so that the client is unable to read or copy it's value.

Can anyone please explain how is that being done or point me to a forum or a site where that method is already explained?

Comment: Maybe this blog will help you, not sure if it is the same for c# but here is an "solution" with JS: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/encrypting-cookies-in-the-browser